# MySQL: LEFT JOIN on tables having same columns

Tags: php, mysql

Here are 3  MySQL tables :

```
CREATE TABLE `t1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);


CREATE TABLE `t2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `a` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `b` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);


CREATE TABLE `t3` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `b` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `c` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

I want to get all data from this tables :

```
select * from t1
left join t2 on t1.id=t2.id
left join t3 on t1.id=t3.id;
```

The result is (with some random data in tables) :

```
+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| id | id   | a    | b    | id   | b    | c    |
+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|  1 |    1 |   42 |   42 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|  2 | NULL | NULL | NULL |    2 |   43 |   43 |
+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I'm using mysqli_result::fetch_object (PHP) to retrieve and process data :

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');

$result = $mysqli->query('select * from t1
    left join t2 on t1.id=t2.id
    left join t3 on t1.id=t3.id;');

var_dump($result->fetch_object());
var_dump($result->fetch_object());
```

So I have 2 objects, but some columns are null :

```
object(stdClass)[3]
  public 'id' => null
  public 'a' => string '42' (length=2)
  public 'b' => null
  public 'c' => null
object(stdClass)[3]
  public 'id' => string '2' (length=1)
  public 'a' => null
  public 'b' => string '43' (length=2)
  public 'c' => string '43' (length=2)
```

I can understand why it happens (some columns have same name), but I'd rather have only non-null values​​! In my case, I have many more tables and many more columns. I can't use aliases on columns because I'm "blind" in my PHP code : I want to use `b` and not an alias of `b`.

So I want to "prefer" non-null value in that query (there is no other order rule).

Comment: yipes - can you show your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the fields, and use the `coalesce` function to get the value of either one:

```
select 
  coalesce(t2.b, t3.b) as b,
  coalesce(t2.c, t3.c) as c
from t1
left join t2 on t1.id=t2.id
left join t3 on t1.id=t3.id;
```

Note though, if both 'b's are not null, then you get only the one in t2. Ans if both are null, you still get null as a result.

PS: MySQL also has the `IFNULL` function. But IFNULL only accepts two values, and it is less portable to other databases, so I prefer coalesce myself.

Comment: `IFNULL` has the same behaviour, but it's slightly faster, however it takes exactly two arguments, while `COALESCE` takes two or more.

Answer (score 0):

Use `->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)` instead. This'll fetch a numbered array instead of string-keyed, so you won't have your "duplicate" field names overwriting each other. You'll get one array entry per field in the query results. But you'll have to be very careful mapping those array entries back to the query, because `$row[7]` is exactly which field in the query? NO way to really be sure.

A better bet would be to alias your fields in the query, so they do have unique names:

```
SELECT t1.a AS t1a, t2.2 AS t2a, etc...
```